# How do I change the Vim font and color scheme for WSL?

Tags: vim, fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I surprisingly couldn't find a proper answer for this online. I've already tried the normal route of creating a `.vimrc` file but it doesn't work.

I found [this blog post](https://myskan.tistory.com/95) and although it's in Korean, it's basically saying that you can open the registry editor and make modifications to `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\C:_Program Files_WindowsApps_CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1604.2017.922.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc_ubuntu.exe]` but the problem is I have no such thing in my editor.

Any other opinions or resources provided are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any generic resources for changing vim font/colors should work, as this is not WSL specific(and the right solution is definitely not changing the registry). Possibly [this site](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/vim-color-schemes), though I don't use vim and don't know if its accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default windows terminal emulator (conemu), you change font and terminal colors by right-clicking the title bar and editing the properties entry (not the defaults entry!).

Vim color schemes are intrinsic and selected by using both the [`background`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27background%27) and [`colorscheme`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27background%27) settings. Please consult the online help included with the editor or read it at [vimhelp.org](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Acolorscheme).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still an issue but this post helped me.
[Enabling syntax color and higlighting](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644480/enabling-vi-syntax-colors-and-highlighting)

No registry editing required. Simply create `.vimrc` and put

```
syntax on
colorscheme darkblue
```

The list of additional color schemes can be found here:

```
ls -l /usr/share/vim/vim*/colors/
```